# libc or glibc in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, glibc, libc

I'm a little bit confused with these libraries. I'm working on Ubuntu now, I use g++ 5 and I see that my applications link in libc.so. Is it a Ubuntu's implementation of C standard library? Is it different from glibc?

```
$ ldd application.exe
...
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
...
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Current Ubuntu uses glibc for the C standard library implementation.  The source package is called [`glibc`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=glibc&searchon=sourcenames&suite=all&section=all), but the installed binary package is called [`libc6`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libc6&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) for historic reasons.  You can see the exact version of the `libc6` package on your system if you run this command:

```
dpkg -l libc6
```

There used to be a temporary fork of glibc called eglibc, but [eglibc development has been abandoned](http://www.eglibc.org/archives/patches/msg01327.html); all active eglibc-specific ports were merged into glibc before that.

Ubuntu also has packages for alternative libc implementations such as [musl](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=musl&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all), but the distribution itself does not use them because it is glibc-based.

Answer (score 10):

Libc is the name of the standard library for the C programming language. Glibc is one of many different implementations of libc. In particular, Glibc is the libc implementation that is developed and maintained as part of the GNU project.

Glibc is one of many different implementations of libc. Some other well-known implementations are the Microsoft Visual C Runtime (which includes a libc), musl, dietlibc, µClibc, the various BSD libcs, and Google Bionic (the libc that is shipped with Android).

Comment: Thank you very much! How can I determine which implementation is used in Ubuntu?

Comment: Unless you use a very specialized Linux distribution, you are using the Glibc.

Comment: I can assure you that [glibc is still very much part of the GNU project](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/). Why do you think so otherwise?

Comment: I'm new to linux, ubunutu etc and I just want to know exactly what implementation if libc, libm I have - to search for a correct documentation for example.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer: I remember a statement to that effect by Ulrich Drepper about 15-20 years ago. I recognize your name, so I'll naturally bow to your expertise.